# preloader image cause Unnecessary ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-loop, infinite-scroll

i have correct infinite loading, that show the other posts
and i have a image preloader.gif at footer
but when i scroll down and the preloader image .show()
this cause Unnecessary double ajax request

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            var contents = {
                  action:                     'infinite_scroll',  
              }
              $( "#infiniteloader" ).show();
            $.post( admax_data.url, contents, function( data ){
                    $( "#infiniteloader" ).hide();
                    $( ".vc_row" ).append( data );
                });
                return false;   
            }
    }); 
});
```

This first .show() and after .hide() caused a double request becouse the page scrolling again
the only way is moving the preloader's image to another place, but not have sense.

How to prevent this double request?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution

if i use this css rule ( display: block/none) this cause double ajax request becouse this create a space between the last post and the footer

the best way is use this rule ( visibility: visible/hidden) becouse this already leave a space between lastpost and footer and not cause double request

Perfect! Solved